# Magento Connect issue

Tags: magento-1.9, module, installation, magento-connect

Everytime I try to install a module through Magento Connect I get sent back to the login screen, but inside Magento connect.

[image]

Comment: Are you using multiple servers or have a different address for your backend?
Also make sure you cache & cookies are clear as that can have this effect sometimes too.

Comment: cache and cookies, cleared magento cache.  Not using multiple server or different address for the backend